# Rolling a die, then rolling another die for unique results

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, random

I will roll a fair 100-sided die. If I get a 1 or 2, I will roll a 40-sided die.

How many times will I have to repeat this experiment until each roll on the 40-sided die appears at least once, on average?

The random generation is uniform, so the probability of getting a 1 or 2 from the 100-sided die is 1/50, and the probability of getting any single number from the 40-sided die is 1/40.

I don't know how to calculate this. I'll show what I was thinking.

Looking at just the 40-sided die, I will roll for a number. If I'm looking for a unique number, then I will always get a unique number on the first roll, so that has probability 1 (or 40/40). The next time, it will be 39/40. But then assuming that I don't get it, it's 39/40 again, but if I do, it's 38/40.

The probability seems to be (1 - q/40), where q is the number of numbers from 1 to 40 that I've already gotten at least once.

So first, there is a (40/40) chance that I get a unique roll.

Then, there is a (39/40) chance that I get one and (1/40) that I don't.

If I did get one there is a (38/40) chance I get one and (2/40) I don't, but if I didn't there is a (39/40) chance that I get one and (1/40) I don't, so in total by this point there should be (40/40)(39/40)(38/40) that I have 3 unique rolls, (40/40)(39/40)(2/40) that I have 2 unique rolls, and (40/40)(1/40) that I have 1 unique roll.

The pattern looks to be (40!)/(40^40) that I get it in 40 rolls and it's not possible to get it in under 40 rolls.

But I'm not sure how to calculate 41 rolls, and so on. I assume there is a final summation at the end but I don't know how to get the terms.

And then all of this is dependent on a (1/50) chance of getting the 1 or 2 from the 100-sided die. So that means the average is the answer multiplied by 50, is it not?

Comment: Preliminary question: if you _don't_ pick $1$ or $2$, then your next pick is in the original range of $1$ to $100$, right? Also, if you pick $1$ or $2$, does that lock you in the $1$ to $40$ range for every future pick you make, or is that only for the very next one?

Comment: @H.sapiensrex Imagine it as a 100-sided die and a 40-sided die. In fact, I'll put that in the question.

Comment: Does the 40 sided die have faces labelled with {1,2,...,40}?

Comment: @kodlu Yes, both are 1...n die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us focus on the second stage to begin with, ie the expected number of throws needed to collect all numbers from $1$ to $40$

Defining success as a new number appearing, the first number requires one throw. After that the number of trials until the second success is geometrically distributed with parameter $p=\frac{39}{40}$, thus mean $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{40}{39}$
and so on, giving an expected value for total throws for getting all $40$ numbers as $1+\frac{40}{39} +\frac{40}{38} + ... \frac{40}1$

Now coming to the first stage. If you have to clear it just once, add $50$ to the above.

On the other hand, if it has to be cleared each time, but the numbers already obtained in the second stage remain counted, multiply by $50$

Comment: I see, thank you. It has to be cleared each time on the first die. So it seems that you are saying the formula would be \sum_(n=1)^(1/q){1/(pqn)}, where p is the probability of success with the 100-sided die, so p is 1/50, and q is the prob. of success with the 40-sided die, so q is 1/40. That means it is equal to (2000/40)+(2000/39)+...+(2000/1), which is about 8557. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome !